# Testing different garbage collection algorithms?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How would one go about creating a program that was specifically designed for testing Garbage Collection aglorithms in Java?  Any articles where this has been done would also be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by testing?  Correctness?  Performance?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework. This question is too general and too vague to arise in practice: at least the specific aspect of interest would then be named. Here's what you are expected to do: find out what garbage collection algorithms exist, find out what the key differences are, think of situations in which those differences would show up and then write a program that creates those situations, so the differences are visible. For bonus points, track down seminal papers on garbage collectors and explain how the different algorithms came into existence exactly because of those differences.